# Can't access old YouTube account even though I know the email, username and password

Tags: youtube

Back in 2006, I created an account/channel on YouTube. The account was linked to my Gmail account, but created before YouTube was acquired by Google. The channel is still online and has a few videos that were uploaded in 2006 or 2007.

I still use my Gmail account, which is now also my Google account. However, even though it's the same email, the Google account is not connected to my old YouTube account. I probably haven't been logged in to the old YouTube account / channel since 2007.

How do I get access to my old YouTube channel, if I don't remember the password?

Update: I now remember the password, but still haven't been able to gain access to the account. See the comment below. I have attempted to claim the account by entering my username and password here: https://www.youtube.com/gaia_link However, I get an error message saying the account can't be claimed.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Follow the directions from [I signed in with a YouTube username](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/55757?hl=en) (official help article)

Comment: I have tried the gaia link, but, as I stated in my question, I wasn't able to remember my password. Now, I think I remember the password, because the error message changed from "the username and password does not match" (or something like that, I use a different language) to "this YouTube account isn't available to be claimed". Why would I not be able to claim the account?

Comment: From the referred link : Note: If you don’t remember your old YouTube password, unfortunately there is no password recovery option for these accounts. Regarding the new message, it's very likely that the account was already claimed. Related: https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/45291073/this-youtube-account-isn-t-available-to-be-claimed-can-still-be-recovered-how?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually just read through that thread, and it didn't offer any solution. Not for the people commenting in the thread either ... Such a weird issue, not being able to access the account when you know both the username and the password AND still have access to the email. This issue is clearly created by Google.

Comment: Hey! I have this exact same problem! Did you find a solution? I'm trying to find a way to contact youtube support, but that seems impossible too.

Comment: @asbjornenge . Hi! No, but I have been thinking about making another attempt, so thank you for the reminder! I just tried the gaia link again and the result is the same. It says the account cannot be claimed. Is it the same for you?

Comment: Yup, exact same error message. And I get a different one if I use the wrong password 